# Join back missing date matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, left-join

I have the following table:

```
| variable | varDate    | match |
|----------|------------|-------|
| var1     | 15/02/2020 | 98    |
| var1     | 16/02/2020 | 99    |
| var1     | 17/02/2020 | 97    |
| var2     | 15/02/2020 | 95    |
```

I would like to populate var2, for the dates 16/02/2020 and 17/02/2020 (those that are missing, and if null, populate with the value 100).

I have a table that contains the last three days in a table, that looks like so:

```
| date       |
|------------|
| 15/02/2020 |
| 16/02/2020 |
| 17/02/2020 |
```

My attempt was to use a left join on varDate = date, however this didn't produce the result I expected like below:

```
| variable | date       | match |
|----------|------------|-------|
| var1     | 15/02/2020 | 98    |
| var1     | 16/02/2020 | 99    |
| var1     | 17/02/2020 | 97    |
| var2     | 15/02/2020 | 95    |
| var2     | 16/02/2020 | 100   |
| var2     | 17/02/2020 | 100   |
```

Comment: which dbms product are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Considering that they tagged [tag:tsql] that *implies* SQL Server @Atk  (or sybase, but let's hope not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
select
    v.variable,
    d.date,
    coalesce(t.match, 100) match
from (select distinct variable from mytable) v
cross join mydates d 
left join mytable t 
    on  t.varDate = d.date
    and t.variable = v.variable
```

This works by first `cross join`ing the distinct values of `variable` available in the table with the table that references the dates (I called it `mydates`). This generates all possible combinations of dates and variables.

Then, we bring in the original table (I assumed `mytable`) with a `left join`. Finally, we use `coalesce()` to assign a default value for missing `match`es.

Ideally, you should have a reference table for the `variable`s as well, which would avoid the need for the `distinct` subquery:

```
select
    v.variable,
    d.date,
    coalesce(t.match, 100) match
from myvariables v
cross join mydates d 
left join mytable t 
    on  t.varDate = d.date
    and t.variable = v.variable
```